# QQ Screen Capture Application

Tags: windows, screenshot, screen-capture

Maybe there are not many people uses QQ but I downloaded it recently and found out the screen capture application is awesome, very easy to use and very effective for such task, much better than paint, gimp and other applications, this is far much easier and effective.

Does anyone know how to use this application without having QQ?¿

Or if with QQ, how to use it without the need of a chat-conversation¿?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

snip. A Tencent screen capture product.
If you are using a Mac, a good tool for you.

http://snip.qq.com/

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you, i use `QQ` at work and discovered its `Screen Capture Plugin`, it seems to use `PhotoFiltreStudio` tool inside of it.

I was searching for long time this tool or similar one with same features as standalone application and found this open and free software : [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/)

It is in top list alternatives for [Windows Snipping Tool](http://alternativeto.net/software/greenshot/)

It is very good and has many other features.

It also has an image editor with full productivity tools.

It just doesn't allow to modify the screen capture in the fly which is very awesome with `QQ` . Also, when i record screen videos i can use it for adding comments on the screen in the fly.

I keep using `QQ` for that.